# Create new admin section in wordpress - for creating office-pages

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, admin

Ok, I have been looking for hours and I have to say I am really lost. I am trying to create a new section in the admin section of wordpress that should enable the user to create a new custom "office" page.

There is really many office pages on the site I have been working on (over 30), each with its opening hours, map, and images. I assume the client will want to add more later (or remove them) and they would like to manage it through Wordpress. That would mean adding a section that would enable them to put in the name of the office, opening hours, images and the location and it would create a new office page. I am rather a front-end developer and I have never worked with Wordpress before. I understand the loop, etc, I have read several things about Themes and how to create them but I am seriously stuck with how to create a section in admin area that would enable page creation/deletion with certain options.

Any help is greatly appreciated, just please point me to the correct direction. Web pages, WP codex, tutorials, youtube... whatever that helps. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Either you use custom [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Taxonomy) or create a new custom post type which is really simple in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**3 steps : -**

**1. create office post type by using [Register Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)**

**2. Create office categories by using [Register taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy)**

**3. create a meta box by using [Add Meta Box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)  for extra fields which wordpress doesnt offer by default like (office hours )**

**hope it helps !**

Answer (score 2):

You can make custom post type..
By writing Code in function.php

```
function function-name(){
    register_post_type( 'post name',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'post name' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'post name' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'post name'),
            'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','comments','custom-fields'),
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'function-name');
```